# Google Map API map there but cut off

Tags: jquery, google-maps

On my site, my map is getting cut off. But im not sure why. I can still interact but only in a limited sense. Can anyone take a look and give me some insight?

here is the site
http://people.rit.edu/~ctn9382/536/assignment3/

in order to get to the map you have to click "show results" and then click a hospital's name and it should create a bunch of stuff on the top of the page.

Comment: Maybe throw in a `position:relative;` in the CSS for the map container? Bizarrely enough, if I hit CTRL-SHIFT-J in Chrome to go to the developer tools, suddenly your map moves to fit nicely in the DIV! edit: actually even resizing the window does the trick, as I should've expected. Maybe try to force a redraw, or something

Answer (score 14):

Whenever the user switches to the Locations tab, force a resize event by firing this:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Since you're initializing the map while the div is hidden, it can't figure out how big to make itself, so you need to force it to check the size again. This is also why it fixes itself when you open the developer console, as Daan noticed, since that resizes the window which fires that resize event.

Comment: I cant get it to work. Would you mind elaborating? it says map is not defined

Comment: "map" is the variable name for your map object in that snippet of code. It sounds like you have probably lost scope on the map object when you're trying to trigger the resize. I'm not entirely sure without seeing the code in detail, but check out the scope issue or make your map object global and it should work.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for the help. Worked perfectly. Should have been accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working this way:

```
var map;
function initialize() {
var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(<%=@listing.lat%>, <%=@listing.lng%>);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 15,
  center: pos,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('listing_map'),
    mapOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos,
    map: map
});
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}
```

Now when you switch tabs, use setTimeout to delay the map initialization:

```
<a href="" onclick="setTimeout(function(){ initialize() }, 100);">
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the map applet hasn't been "told" to fill the container.  Without code examples I can't offer concrete changes but I suggest that you look into the CSS style for the map applet.  You may need to set the width and height to a specific size (the width and height of the container) or it may be as simple as telling it to take 100% of available space.

Best of luck to you.

Comment: thanks i looked into it. the weird thing is, if i inspect element on anything, it goes back to normal and nothing is wrong, even if i close firebug

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, got it fixed though thanks to some helpful folks here on the forum.

[Solved my issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006618/my-google-maps-is-cut-off-im-wondering-why-javascript-v)